# Can I emulate internet when PC is offline?

Tags: networking

I'm making a application with networking. It consists of a client and a server. Client connects to server which is hosted at 127.0.0.1.

The networking functionality is provided by an engine (Unity 4.3). It does not work when a PC is offline, saying that it could not retrieve an internal IP address.

Can I emulate a network connection to get an internal ip?

Comment: It is likely that unity connects to their main servers if you don't have a licensed version of unity, and may cause your application not to work just because of that. Are you owning a commercial license for unity?

Comment: Unity allows to setup local MasterServer. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-MasterServerBuild.html

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I meant. I was talking about a licensing service.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your application is doing, what your network looks like, or what the Unity app is doing.  But, TCP/IP works perfectly fine on a local-only network assuming you have things properly configured.

Comment: But can I set it up with no router?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to specify your IP address manually, but the problem might be Unity engine not working except when connected to a valid internet connection.